# How to exclude items from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

In the PHP function below, I want to exclude `cat_ID=1`

How can I do it?

```
function get_cats(){
    $post_cats= array();
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach($categories as $cat){
        array_push($post_cats, $cat->cat_ID);
    }
    return $post_cats;
}
```

get_the_category() returns an array of all the categories that the current post is assigned to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($categories as $cat){  
    if ($cat->cat_ID == 1)
       continue;
    array_push($post_cats, $cat->cat_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    if ($cat->cat_ID != 1) {
        $post_cats[] = $cat->cat_ID;
    }
}
```

That'll exlude the value as the array's built. Otherwise you can use array search operations to get key corresponding to that particular ID value later on, and then unset() that particular key.

Answer (score 1):

Very very trivial question. Use

```
if ($cat->cat_ID != 1)
```

just before the `array_push`